# linux with 3.2.x kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there a major Linux distribution that uses 3.2.x kernel?

Comment: Although I know that this is not a great question, but I think its better to consider that one who asked it is a very new to our community and is better (again) to not down-vote it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Backtrack 5 R2 uses 3.2.6 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04 seems pretty major as well. It's on 3.2.0.